# "Value cannot be null error" in PublishPipelineArtifact task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use the PublishPipelineArtifact task in my fist yaml pipeline, but I'm getting the following error no matter what I try:

```
Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish pipeline artifact
Description  : Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run. Published artifacts can be downloaded in other jobs, stages, or pipelines using the "Download pipeline artifact" task.
==============================================================================
##[error]Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: PublishPipelineArtifact (ecdc45f6-832d-4ad9-b52b-ee49e94659be/1.0.0)
Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
```

Currently this is the publish task in my yml file:

```
trigger: none

variables:  

# agent/environment variables
- group: VARS_AGENT

stages:

- stage: build

  jobs:

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #- job: 'artifacts_debug'
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  - job: 'artifacts_debug'
    displayName: 'Debug pipeline artifacts'
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: '$(AgentPoolName)'
      demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
    steps:  

    # show artifact staging dir contents
    - script: 'echo test > "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\test.txt" '
      displayName: 'Create dummy file'

    - script: 'dir "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"  /s /b '
      displayName: 'Show artifact staging contents'

    - script: 'echo AgentPoolName=$(AgentPoolName)  /s /b '
      displayName: 'Echo AgentPoolName variable content'

    #publish artifacts ("new" pipeline artifacts but can't get it to work)
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifact: Db
```

What am I doing wrong? The \db folder in the ArtifactStagingDirectory exists, and is not empty. The variable group VARS_AGENT resolves correctly, showing the expected value in the debug "echo" step.

Comment: Which agent do you use? Hosted? Or your self hosted agent? It looks there's no error on your YAML, and it's all work on my side. Could you share the completed YAML here? Including some key variable value, such as `$(AgentPoolName)`.

Comment: Self-hosted windows agent (version: 2.150.3 ).

I stripped everything from the YAML until I ended with the below, but I still get that same error (see updated YAML definition in the question)

Comment: Appreciate your sharing. I tested your YAML code on my side with self-hosted agent(2.155.1) and everything work. https://imgur.com/a/wGvJZ2J  Could you try again with upgrading your agent version?

Comment: Hi @MerlinLiang-MSFT , indeed upgrading  (I was on 2.150.x) solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jay’s comment, the issue should caused by the agent version instead of wrong YAML. Now, the latest version is 2.155.1, but Jay’s agent version is 2.150.

After upgrade the agent version to latest, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw that you are using a "path" parameter.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) it's called "targetPath":

```
# Publish pipeline artifact
# Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    #targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)' 
    #artifact: # Optional
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however the parameter to targetPath doesn't help. Interestingly, the code example on that page mentions "targetPath", but the argument documentation a few lines lower has "path".

Comment: Update: after upgrading the agent the publish worked, both `path`and `targetPath` are valid, it seems

Comment: @JayReally yes, targetpath is equal with path.